# rCharts with shiny, Cannot see the rChart in Shiny

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I want to create rChart for my data extracted from a mysql database. As shown in ui.R and server.R created ggplot is visible but not the rChart? Can anyone explain what has gone wrong here?

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library("shinyBS", lib.loc="/home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
require("rCharts")
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')
# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(


    fluidRow(

        column(width=4,             
               plotOutput("sales")
        ),
        column(width=8,  
               showOutput("salesR","polycharts")            
        )


    )
         )
    ))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library("DBI", lib.loc="/home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
library("RMySQL", lib.loc="/home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="/home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
library("shinyBS", lib.loc="/home/thisa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
require("rCharts")
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
user="root",password="891208",host="localhost",dbname="openPos")
# Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

sales_total <- reactive({ "SELECT ospos_sales.sale_time, 
 CAST(sale_time AS date) AS sale_date, ospos_sales.employee_id, 
 ospos_sales.sale_id,  ospos_sales_items.line,
 ospos_sales_items.quantity_purchased,    
 ospos_sales_items.item_cost_price, 
 ospos_sales_items.item_unit_price, 
 ospos_sales_items.discount_percent, 
 ospos_suppliers.person_id, 
 ospos_suppliers.company_name, 
 ospos_items.name, ospos_items.category,
 ospos_items.supplier_id, 
 ospos_items.item_number, 
 ospos_items.quantity,
 ospos_items.reorder_level, 
 ospos_items.location, 
 sum(quantity_purchased * item_unit_price-item_unit_price*(discount_percent/100)) 
 AS revenue, sum(quantity_purchased * item_cost_price) AS cost
                            FROM ospos_sales, ospos_sales_items, 
                            ospos_suppliers,   ospos_items
                            WHERE ospos_sales.sale_id = ospos_sales_items.sale_id
                            AND ospos_sales_items.item_id = ospos_items.item_id
                            AND ospos_items.supplier_id = ospos_suppliers.person_id
                            GROUP BY sale_time"})
salesTotal <- reactive({dbGetQuery(con,sales_total())})
output$sales <- renderPlot
 ({ 
                          p<-ggplot(salesTotal(),
  aes_string(x="sale_time",y="revenue"))+geom_point()
                          print(p)})
  output$salesR <- renderChart({
   m1 <- rPlot(revenue ~ sale_time, data = salesTotal(),type='point')
   return(m1)
 })
 })
```

Comment: there's a possible conflict with `shinyBS`, does it work when you remove it ?

Comment: Add `m1$set(dom = "salesR")` so that the id of the created `rChart` matches up with what what is in your UI. Alternately you can use `renderChart2`, which handles it for you in a different way.

Comment: Thank you Ramnath It worked. By the way many thanks to your rCharts project great piece of work.